# How to use cursor in jdbc to get resultSet of a Select query in batches

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc, cursor

I have a very large dataset in a table in the database. I want to get it in my java code.I am using `Statement.executeQuery` to get the result of the `SELECT` statement. But the ResultSet obtained from this query is too large that I am getting heap memory out of space exception.

I read about using cursor in jdbc to get few results from a query in the following [link](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#fetchsize-example). I wanted to use this to fetch the whole result but in small batches. Is that possible to achieve using cursor.

Comment: The link you posted certainly does suggest that it is *possible*, so what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I need to get all of the results in small batches. But I am not sure how to do that.The link kets me get just small number of rows say x. I need to get all the result in batches of x.

Comment: Did you see the part where it says "A small number of rows are cached on the client side of the connection and when exhausted the next block of rows is retrieved by repositioning the cursor." ...?

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks. I think I missed that part. Its clear now.